# PHP Need Needed

Tags: php, mysql

I want the result of that above query but instead of the result of the query , the query is itself printed , not the result of it ? why?

```
     <?php

     $host = 'localhost';
       $user = 'root';
       $passwd = '';
     $database = 'p_database';
   $connect = mysql_connect($host,$user,$passwd) or die("could not connect to database");

     $query = "SELECT DATE(order_time) AS date, SUM(Quantity) AS total_sales
    FROM ss_orders,ss_ordered_carts
    GROUP BY date";
    mysql_select_db($database);
   $result = mysql_query ($query,$connect);

      print "$query";
     ?>
```

Comment: Because you told it `print "$query";`

Comment: i am confused ?i want the query result , like that total sale of it? , i am not sure if this is the correct way or i am missing some part

Comment: What tutorial are you using to learn PHP?

Comment: i didnt code for like months , almost a year and i cant recall it back , i had my previous project files and so , so trying to learn from those , if i can recall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you had printed the $query , so please modify your code

```
 mysql_select_db($database,$connect);
 $result = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($query));
 print_r($result);
```

Comment: i am getting resource ID #4? what is it?

Comment: Array ( [date] => 2014-01-20 [total_sales] => 2 ) this is the result i am getting?its right but is there any way where i can only get like date:todays date and total sale:2

Comment: you manually need to do so using php if statement, and you cant use  total sale as array key because space in key not acceptable

Comment: do you have any example of IF statement for doing this ? if possible,Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `Print_r` or `echo` instead of `Print`

```
<?php

     $host = 'localhost';
     $user = 'root';
     $passwd = '';
     $database = 'p_database';
     $connect = mysql_connect($host,$user,$passwd) or die("could not connect to database");

     $query = "SELECT DATE(order_time) AS date, SUM(Quantity) AS total_sales
        FROM ss_orders,ss_ordered_carts
        GROUP BY date";
     mysql_select_db($database);
     $result = mysql_query ($query,$connect);
     while(mysql_fetch_array($result)){
       echo $result[1];
     }

 ?>
```

Comment: question is asked why TS is getting the query instead of the results. With echo and print_r you would get the mysql result object, not the results itself.

Comment: Thanks Mr Sameer But This Method Wont Work

Comment: @Luceos Not event the `mysql` result object. All this does is echo the query -> _"SELECT DATE(order_time) AS date, SUM(Quantity) AS total_sales FROM ss_orders,ss_ordered_carts GROUP BY date"_...

Comment: Sorry @Shahchaki i was confused, now edited my answer try it.@Luceos its better to answer and help then check other's mistake.

Comment: @Sameer I am sorry but i still cant,@Karthick Kumar Ganesh Code Is Working ,Thanks For You're Helped :) Appreciated

Comment: @sameer; answering is useful if the answer is not yet given. It was given, though it was not yours. I provide feedback as why I downvote, so you are able to correct and improve. I was mistaken however on the exact result of the $result and therefor I apologize. I also see you updated the question, which will make a downvote unnecessary.